# Error using subsref Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: mysql, matlab, image-processing, cell-array

I'm querying a database for license plate numbers. When the license plate is correct everything works great, but if the license plate is not in database, I get an error.

```
conn = database('baze', 'root', 'root', 'Vendor', 'MYSQL', 'Server', 'localhost', 'PortNumber', 3306);
setdbprefs('datareturnformat','structure');
sqlquery = ['select vardas, pavarde, laipsnis, pareigos, telefonas, marke, numeris, tarnyba, nuotrauka from info '...
       'where numeris = ' '''' word '''']; 
curs = exec(conn, sqlquery);
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray');
curs = fetch(curs);
numeris = curs.data{7}; %Error thrown by this line
if strcmp(word, curs.data{7})
    set(handles.text13,'foregroundcolor','green');
    set(handles.text13,'string','ENTRY');
else
    set(handles.text13,'foregroundcolor','red');
    set(handles.text13,'string','DO NOT ENTRY');
end
close(curs);
close(conn);
```

It looks like i don't have 7 cells in my cell array. I don't know how fix this.

Comment: Check that you have results before trying to index into them? If you don't have any matches from your query and so an empty array is returned. You can do something like: `if isempty(curs.data); % don't do anything`

Comment: it works if i dont do task after isemty, but i need program disp DO NOT ENTRY, and if i do task got same error

Comment: Just delete `numeris = curs.data{7}` and change your conditional to be: `if ~isempty(curs.data) && strcmp(word, curs.data{7})`

Comment: still got same error

Comment: solve function if isempty(curs) || ~isstruct(curs) || ~isfield(curs, 'data') || size(curs.data,2) < 7

Comment: and try catch function